# Will anybody help me gauge the quality of my question?

Tags: discussion

Will anyone help me gauge the quality of my [Views question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/what-is-the-key-concept-i-need-to-know-in-order-to-expose-a-cck-checkbox-widget)? The format of SE as QA—and not discussion—makes it difficult to get some questions I have about Drupal [even started](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/can-date-api-calendar-and-cck-send-an-argument-to-views-with-data-from-a-field), if they are not asked well.

I'm surprised my seemingly simple [Views question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12883/what-is-the-key-concept-i-need-to-know-in-order-to-expose-a-cck-checkbox-widget) has gone unanswered. I tried hard to write up the useful info for the Views interface, too. Then again is it that simple?

I would think the points system at SE should be incentive enough for any seasoned vet to jump in, answer a gim'me, and collect more points...

Or, maybe the question is somehow...boorish? Am I too much of a Drupal noobie?

Answer (score 2):

I read the question, and I don't really understand what you are trying to do.  I think the questions is either

1. Too specific to your situation for others to comprehend.
2. Worded poorly

Answer (score 2):

> The format of SE as QA—and not discussion—makes it difficult to get some questions I have about Drupal [even started](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6427/can-date-api-calendar-and-cck-send-an-argument-to-views-with-data-from-a-field), if they are not asked well.

I don't think the format of the site makes a difference. If users don't understand what you are asking, they will ask you in a comment, and if you keep asking questions for which they have to ask you what exactly you mean, then they will probably stop commenting.
If you have provided all the necessary information, then it is probable that the question is too specific that nobody has a solution for your case.

Let's analyze your question.

> It is my goal to make both weight and a custom flag widgets exposed in an admin page for a *list Views view* (the weight data field is problematic and I have another post addressing it at the moment). The goal of this Views view is two pages: an end-user page as a plain HTML list, and an admin page with *editable widgets* for flag and weight.

- It's not clear what you mean by *list Views view*. Literally, it would be a view that lists the views defined in the site, but then it's not clear why you are referring to content types.
- *Widgets* is not the term used by Drupal when referring to form fields, which are simply called *form fields*.
- A view simply shows a list of nodes, users, or other Drupal entities that match some criteria defined from the view itself. What you call *editable widgets*, which I suppose it means a form field that allows to edit the value being shown, doesn't exist in Views.

> In this question, I am working on a boolean checkbox that does not display on the admin page, even though the block is listed on the site's block admin page in a visible region.

- It is still not clear to which admin page you are referring, as it is not clear to which block you are referring. You could be referring to a view that is used as a block, but you didn't say that.

> I've read the implementation of a checkbox *widget* is a special block.

- Drupal gives to *block* a specific meaning, which is the meaning you seem referring to in the previous sentence. A checkbox is not a block; it's just a form field.

> Selecting an item in the list will produce the "focus" of the selection in the block (rather than check boxes embedded in the list itself).

- When I select an item in a list, the focus is still on the list. It's not clear which block should receive the focus, and what you are calling *block*; you used the term to mean two different things, and it's now not clear to which of them you are referring.

> If the widget is in the content type, the view has that content in fields, and the block is set to display in the template, what is still missing? What "thread" or concept for the implementation of widgets ties these all together?

- It's not clear what you are asking. A content type has a field, the view is showing nodes of that content type, and the view is used to create a block. What should be missing?

Comment: Do you understand the question?

Comment: Don't get me wrong! I like the StackEx format. It does not serve all needs equally. The discussion format has been around for some time and its modes of communication are well known and understood. (This site, to my knowledge, is a rarity of rigorous Q&A.)

What is it about a "discussion" which enables some problems to be resolved in a more efficient manner? First, the problem must be form-able into a question. Secondly, the person asking the question must have sufficient understanding to ask the question, or both parties must share a common set of terms separating knowns from unknowns.

Comment: Let me expound on this. It perposterous to imagine, with the capability of detail you were able to garner from my question, that I was asking about RSS, for example. I explicitly refer to the Views module and you responded correctly to the topic of the Views module. Anyone who uses the Views module would naturally understand the Drupal Way of pulling content out of a node uses Views. Thus, for Views to display anything, there has to be something in the database.

Comment: I have included the content type's overview to indicate *there are* fields capable of containing boolean data. And the data, once drawn from the View, will need to be displayed. While Views itself does contain the necessary functionality to put a node into a template, what is not clear--as it is a central theme of the post--is just how the designation of a boolean in a content type is expressed in Views. And finally, if there is a function to expose the widget, then it might need to be included in a region, and hence the reason for adding the region information into the original post.

Comment: Everything required for the analysis of my question, which you have so deftly performed (did you need to compose that in a separate text file? Its ok if you did), was available in my post all along. You have even provided the answer. I think now, after this exchange, it would be clear this problem that I had would truly be at home in a discussion format: it is a mistaken assumption that the Views module handles editable forms. 

Thank you. If you would like to post the same. I will check you in as the answerer.

Comment: That is, unless your 12.6K points have made you a jaded prick.(^_^)

Comment: I answered to why your question was not clear; I didn't answer to your question on Drupal Answers.